# Tic Tac Toe how to disable other's move in a period time

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm just C# newbie C#, and I'm trying to build a Tic Tac Toe game in Windows Forms in which player will play with the computer. Each one will have to make their move in a certain amount of time. If they don't, the turn will skip to the opponent. Here is the tricky part. When it comes to the computer's turn, I wanna disable the player action, so he cannot interfere with the computers. Is it possible to do that ? and how would I implement in my code ?

Edit: I didn't realize that the computer move is almost instantly, so it does not matter if I disable the player or not. Thanks anyone for your inputs.

Comment: Uh, how long does the computer take to make a move?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: what have you tried so far?  at this point, without any example or sample of what you're doing, we can only hypothesize.

Comment: you should keep track of whose turn it is

Comment: and yes... the computer will almost certainly play so fast that it is silly to even worry about timing the computer

Comment: @John Saunders: basically, there is a text box for user to enter how many seconds for each move before starting the game

Comment: @GrantWinney And a Thread.Sleep() will make it look like the computer is just thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the play area inside a Container eg: GroupBox and disable/ enable it depending on the requirement. This has to be on the UI thread. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

With no code its hard to see where you are at.

Just use a Boolean and an if statement to disable player interaction if it is the computers turn.

A Boolean to detect if its the computers turn.
A if statement to disable player interaction if it is the computers turn.

```
if(computersTurn==false){
   Allow UI/Clicking
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a pause according to voddy's answer, but any computer pause would be purely for effect as Derek mentioned. One simple thing you could do is to just create a timer, and when the timer event fires regularly, switch to the opponents turn and/or disable the UI as required.